# Regular expression: match a pattern that contains space

Tags: python, string, string-matching

Suppose I want to match some words but with the following rules:

1. the word must be split by a space
2. A "*" character can be in place of any characters in the pattern, including the space
3. The pattern can occur in between two words or as a standalone word

For example, "st ar" would be a match in the string "first ark star" but not "star", and "s*tar" would be a match in "first arks*tar" because the pattern still must contain one whitespace but "*" can replace the white space (any of "s", "t", "a", "r", " ")

I was expecting `[(star)\ ]` to work but it also matches incomplete or out-of-order words. For example, "sa tr" gives two matches when there isn't supposed be a match. I was wondering if lookahead is necessary and if matching is possible with regex?

Comment: Maybe something like [`s[ *]?t[ *]?a[ *]?r(?<!star)`](https://regex101.com/r/0c3jKo/1) though this would match the `s` `t` `a` `r` sequence with any *optional* space or `*` in between but exclude the exact word `star` by use of a *negative lookbehind*. So this would also match such as `s t ar` or `s*t a*r`...

Comment: Further be aware that your current pattern is a [*character class*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). It matches [one character from the listed](https://regex101.com/r/Wq4rLr/1).

Answer (score 0):

I am not absolutely sure that I understand what you are trying to do.
I think this might be what you are looking for :
`[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+\*[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]*\*[a-zA-Z]* [a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]*\*[a-zA-Z]*`

If it is not, then you should probably consider doing it with a matching algorithm instead of a regex.